# Java Spark Mongodb connector joda time save

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

When I save person dataset in mongodb using spark connector, its creating empty object of createdTimestamp as shown below mage , I want to save createdTimestamp with DateTime Object of joda time.

[image: timeStamp is not having any value]

Pseudo code:

```
Dataset<Person> person = person_records.map(person -> {
         person.setAge(10);
         DateTime ts=DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);//date time is joda time 
         person.setCreatedTimestamp(ts);
         person.setApproved(true);
                 return   person;
    }, Encoders.bean(Person.class));
    MongoSpark.save(person);
```

Comment: Can you add some more details, inputs, expected output and what did not work?

Comment: @koiralo, attached  image shows createdTimestamp showing Object with ZERO fields instead of Date Object of joda time.